# How can I write this code better? Is it correct to use the switch command in this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
  public int? GetNextStationId(int StationId, int NextStationId, int LineId, int Mode)
        {
           
            int? nextStationid = 0;
            if (StationId != 0)
            {
                int order = _orderRepository.GetOrder(NextStationId, LineId);
                if (Mode == 1)
                {
                    nextStationid = GetNextStationIdInArrival(LineId, order);
                }
                int orderminusOne = Get(StationId, LineId, order).Item2;

                if (orderminusOne < _orderRepository.LastOrderToModeBack(LineId))
                {
                    nextStationid = 0;
                    return nextStationid;
                }
                if (order != 0)
                {
                    nextStationid = _orderRepository.GetStationId(LineId, orderminusOne);
                    return nextStationid;
                }
                nextStationid = 0;
                return nextStationid;
            }
            return nextStationid;

        }
```

I wrote this code with nested ifs, I want to write cleaner code

Comment: This feel very opinion based. There are so many ways to write code and many opinions along the way. e.g. Instead of passing in a `Mode` you might want to look at various state machine patterns. The more patters you learn over time the more options you will have to help solve problems in elegant ways.

Comment: Could remove one nested if by replacing `if (StationId != 0) {}` with `if (StationId == 0) return 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask the best way to write a piece of code from five different people, they will give five different answers. However, I have fixed some obvious issues in your code for improved readability.

```
public int GetNextStationId(int StationId, int NextStationId, int LineId, int Mode) {

    if (StationId == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int order = _orderRepository.GetOrder(NextStationId, LineId);
    int orderminusOne = Get(StationId, LineId, order).Item2;

    if (orderminusOne < _orderRepository.LastOrderToModeBack(LineId))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (order != 0)
    {
        return _orderRepository.GetStationId(LineId, orderminusOne);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have made this code more readable, but you also changed the results. For instance if `Mode == 1` you are immediatealy doing `return GetNextStationIdInArrival(LineId, order);`.  That's not what the original code does. Because it may still set the `result = 0` based on the other two conditions ... Your code won't allow that. Not sure, which is the intendend behaviour. But in any case, your code is not functionally equivalent to OP's code

Comment: Now your code is completely missing the call to `GetNextStationIdInArrival`. We don't know what this call does. It may have necessary side-effects. You cannot just drop it ...

Comment: Yeah. But according to the name, it's supposed to "GetNextStationIdInArrival"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your code is correct to start with. Why check if `Mode == 1` and set `nextStationid` if it's always going to be overwritten? I might be missing something, but I think this is the same. If you do need to make a call to `GetNextStationIdInArrival` because it has side-effects, make it but don't use the result since it's always overwritten. Consider an enum for those states instead of magic numbers (0).

```
if (StationId == 0)
    return 0;

int order = _orderRepository.GetOrder(NextStationId, LineId);
int orderminusOne = Get(StationId, LineId, order).Item2;

if (orderminusOne < _orderRepository.LastOrderToModeBack(LineId))
    return 0;

if (order != 0)
{
    int? nextStationid = _orderRepository.GetStationId(LineId, orderminusOne);
    return nextStationid;
}

return 0;
```